# Storing form data in database

Tags: php

Helllo friends

I have developed a form.Which allows the user to store there data.now when i am storing the data wat all care i must take so that my any wrong values are not inserted.Or it is not hacked

Comment: You will have to give us more detail on what you are trying to do. I understand that you have a form and want to do something with the posted data before you save it, but I have no idea *what* you want to do.

Comment: You need to add some more detail about what "wrong values" consist of, and where you are storing the data.

Comment: You should probably divide this up into two separate questions too. "Getting the data you want" and "Avoiding security issues" are different problems. (The latter, BTW, has lots of duplicates on SO already though, so do a search for that instead).

Comment: I take ten fields from user.Some wat like his name(textbox).,address,His interest..Most of them r textbox and radio buttons.Once the user click submit i need to store them in database for further processing of fields

Comment: @david I am concern about the security issues..Wat can be the possible security issues.And how can i avoid them my doing server side validation .Before storing in database..

Comment: As I said. SEARCH: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+mysql+security

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking about is called input validation, and there's [a lot of information](http://www.google.com/search?q=php+input+validation) about it out there.

There are primarily two parts:

1. Making sure the user put in something useful.
2. Making sure the user didn't put in something harmful.

The former is most often done via JavaScript on the client side (for a generally smoother user experience and fewer postbacks).  It should be re-done on the server side as well just to make sure, since you should never trust user input.  Basically it involves things like regular expressions to check the format of an email address, enums to check the value of a drop down list, etc.

The latter must be done server side because you should *never trust user input*.  It involves escaping strings against SQL injection attacks, validating field length against buffer overflow attacks (less common these days), etc.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you need to understand about 2 means of security.

- Sanitation
- Validation

Sanitation is cleaning data so that when you validate your data after removing any unneeded validation flaws.

Sanitation consists of removing characters such as non-visible chars (space,tabs,new-lines, ...) and they should be done across the board.

After validation your data, such as `if(strlen($_GET['key']) > 0)`, you will be inserting the data to your database, but the ways of doing this varies depending on the database type

PHP Offers functions to escape data such as [mysql_real_espae_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

This method is refereed to as Database Escaping.

Comment: This really helped me out.I will do more research in that.I just inserted something like below in my NAME field which is of text type.<script>echo "hello"</script>.When i clicked on submit it echo me "hello" message..N same thing got stored in mysql database

Comment: you should never change data from a user thats gets inserted to the database, you should always keep that raw, apart from executing mysql_real_escape_string on the data. then depending on what interface your using the data on, such as html page, you would escape the data before showing it to the user. this way you still leave other interfaces open to handle the data differently because sometimes the someone typing `<script>` may be intended, such as code sharing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to validate your input, you can do this by Javascript functions which check the input before the form is submitted or you can also call PHP functions to check the values that the form submits before they are stored to a database. If you are using PHP you can opt to learn MVC frameworks such as [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/) or CakePHP which make this process a whole lot easier and more friendly for you as a developer. Such frameworks normally have libraries with code for validations so you just need to use them and not write your own.